# Matching any printable character but whitespace

Tags: regular-expressions

I would like to match a word (that can contain any printable characters except space) separated on the left side by whitespace and on the right side by a newline or whitespace.

What is the difference between these two regex's:

1. `[[:space:]]*\\([^[:space:]]+?\\)\\(?:[[:space:]]|$\\)`
2. `[[:space:]]*\\([[:graph:]]*\\)`

And why does the first one not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first one, the `or` isn't escaped.
I prefer a less fancy regex:

```
"\\s-\\([^\n\t ]+\\)[ \n\t]"
```

But it's a matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: Yes, I realized that I forgot to put "\\" in front of `|`.. thanks. But what if a line ends with `"\r\n"` like in DOS?

Comment: Is `"[[:space:]]"` exactly equal to `"\\s-"` ?

Comment: Yes, it's equal. And you could use `[ \n\t\r]`.

Comment: @HåkonHægland you will only get `^R` in a buffer, if Emacs wasn't able to figure out file's encoding, but if all went ok, even in MS DOS encoded files `\n` will match the line end.

Comment: Also, `[[:space:]]`, `\s-` and `[ \n\t\r]` all mean the same thing.

Comment: @wvxvw But if I use `\n` to match end of line, and the line ends with `\r\n` then the capture group will contain the `\r`? And that is not desired...

Comment: @HåkonHægland nope, you simply never get that character, if the file was parsed properly, Emacs pretends all line ends are just `\n`.  You would need to specifically `C-q c-r` to get that character in an otherwise valid file.